# Basic question from vector analysis - Louis Brand Ch1, problem 2

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, vectors

I am an open university second-year math undergrad student. I am taking a first course on multivariable calculus - I am solving problems from *Vector analysis by Louis Brand* to gain a physics-based intuition to what's going on.

I would like someone to verify my simple proof - or possible suggest alternate line of thought.

> Show that $\vec{AB}+\vec{CD}=2\vec{MN}$, where $M$ and $N$ are the mid-points of $AC$ and $BD$.

**Solution.**

$\begin{aligned}
\vec{MN} &= \vec{AN}-\vec{AM}\\
&= (\vec{AB} + \vec{BN}) - \frac{1}{2}\vec{AC}\\
&= \vec{AB} + \frac{1}{2}\vec{BD} - \frac{1}{2} \vec{AC}\\
&= \vec{AB} + \frac{1}{2}(\vec{BC} + \vec{CD}) - \frac{1}{2}(\vec{AB} + \vec{BC}) \\
&= \frac{1}{2}(\vec{AB} + \vec{CD})\\
2\vec{MN} &= \vec{AB} + \vec{CD}
\end{aligned}$

Comment: Looks good to me:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The posted proof is correct.

For an alternative, express everything in terms of position vectors relative to an arbitrary origin $O$. With the notation $\,x=\vec{OX}\,$, and using that $\,m = (a+c)/2\,$ and $\,n = (b+d)/2\,$:

$$
\begin{align}
\vec{AB}+\vec{CD} &= (b-a)+(d-c) = (b+d)-(a+c) = 2n -2m =2(n-m)=2\vec{MN}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: It occurred to me later, that this is the mid-point formula, but relative to vector $a$. Enjoying doing this.

Comment: @Quasar Yes, you may look at it that way as well. You can find more properties of the bimedians at [https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/AnyQuadri.shtml](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/AnyQuadri.shtml) for example.